# .htaccess redirect issue back to homepage

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a smallr edirect issue with a clients website! Now I want all of the links to redirect to the ssl and www version of the website. This is what I have on the htaccess file now...

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</ifModule>
```

the problem arises when a non-https link is clicked to a specific page.
for example if someone clicks http://www.example.com/somepage it automatically gets redirected to the actual homepage of the site and not the specific page itself!

am I missing something here?
Many thanks.

Comment: Can you show your full .htaccess?

Comment: "redirected to the actual homepage" - So, it's being redirected to `https://www.example.com/`? What happens if you request `https://example.com/somepage`? _Aside:_ You should redirect to the canonical hostname in the first (HTTPS) redirect, otherwise, a request for `http://example.com/...` is going to result in 2 redirects, which is unnecessary.

Comment: No not at all! what happens is this: `http://example.com/somepage` -> `https://www.example.com` while `https://example.com/somepage` -> `https://www.example.com/somepage` so any none ssl link to an example page should goto the ssl version of that page but what is happening its going to the ssl version of the homepage. does that make sense?